# Magento2.2.5 - getting error

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart, https, interface

I got the below error in magento 2.2.5
Interface `Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface' not found in /var/www/html/app/code/Sm/CartQuickPro/Controller/Product/Compare/Remove.php`

Comment: Please post your controller code? `app/code/Sm/CartQuickPro/Controller/Product/Compare/Remove.php`

Comment: install correct version of module Sm_CartQuickPro. HttpPostActionInterface is for M2.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using `Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface` in your controller?

As I see, Magento 2.3.x has this interface class, but it doesn't exist in lowser version 2.2.x.